# How to place table cells different way when orientation is horizontal in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

sorry to bother programmers again, 
I'm writing a simple app, and one of the view controllers has a table.
I'm new to all of this so I found some videos and programmed the table. This is the code above classes (honestly I still don't understand what it does):

```
    extension ViewController3: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("you tapped me!")
    }
}
extension ViewController3: UITableViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

And this is the class:

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tView: UITableView!
    let names = [
    "Alex",
    "Andrew",
    "Mary",
    "Henry"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tView.delegate = self
        tView.dataSource = self
        
    }
}
```

It works fine but the task is when the orientation of the phone/simulator is horizontal, to SHOW the table not in one row, but 2x2 (like 4 cells - 2 rows, 2 lines). I don't know where to search it, I found some tips about placing elements in this way but it's not for a table. And I don't know whether its possible or not. Thank you all in advance

Comment: A table view always has one column; one cell per row. You can use a collection view for different layouts by configuring an appropriate item size and using a flow layout.  You can start by searching for some collectionview tutorials.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you!! I will